# Harmonic Oscillators: Expectation value of the exponential of ladder operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, harmonic-oscillator, open-quantum-systems

I am working with a spin-boson model. To figure out how the off-diagonal elements of the reduced density matrix for the system evolve, I need to figure out $\langle e^C\rangle$ where $C= c_{1}a+c_2a^{\dagger}$ where $a,a^{\dagger}$ are environment harmonic oscillator ladder operators, and the expectation is over the initial state of the environment.

The thesis I'm reading claims that for such $C$, $$\langle e^C\rangle =e^{\langle C^{2}\rangle/2}.$$
I have been trying to prove this (by expanding, and using trace properties, BCH, etc.) for a while and have not been able to do so yet.

To make things easier, I assumed that the harmonic oscillator state is a thermal equilibrium state, so the state of the environment then is $$e^{\beta H}/Z$$ with $Z=Tr(\beta H)$- that makes things a little easier, but I still can't prove the claim.

Any hints would help.

For reference (on pg. 94 of [Understanding and Controlling Open Quantum Systems](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/48677677.pdf)) [image]

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @TobiasFünke, done.

Answer (score 2):

It is a property of ladder operators that their expectation values for certain states (like thermal states) vanish: $\langle \hat{a}\rangle = \langle \hat{a}^{\dagger}\rangle = 0$. This property can then be generalized to all uneven products of ladder operators. When the exponentiated operator is expanded and all the uneven products of ladder operators are removed so that only the even products remain, then the reconstituted exponentiated operator will contain the square of the original exponent in its exponent, times a half. Hope it helps. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: I understand what you say about even products. However, on the left we have these even products inside $\langle \dots \rangle$ but on the right we have terms like $(\langle  C^2 \rangle)^n$. It is this moving into and out of $\langle \dots \rangle $ that I don't get.

Comment: Only the ladder operators are affected by the expectation value. The c-number quantities with which the ladder operators are multiplied are not affected and can be pulled out of the expectation value.

Comment: By C, I mean the whole linear combination of the creation and annihilation operators. For example, I end up with terms like $\langle C^2 / 2 \rangle^2$ in the expansion on the right-hand side. But on the left, I get terms like $\langle C^4  \rangle$. Apologies for getting back so late. I'll try to be more prompt.

Comment: If you multiply out the terms of $C^n$ you get multiple ladder operators in each term together with c-numbers. That is what I am talking about.

Comment: Yes, I understand. What I mean is when I try to compute the terms that appear on the left and the terms that appear on the right, they don't seem to match even when I use the fact that you say in your answer. And as far as I can tell, the problem seems to be coming from the fact that $\langle C^2\rangle^2$ is not the same as $\langle C^4 \rangle$.

Comment: For concreteness, I end up comparing terms like $\langle a^{\dagger}a\rangle^2$ with terms like $\langle (a^{\dagger}a)^2\rangle$. I do not think they are the same for linear combinations of the number states.

Comment: Remember, in an expansion you will get all the possible orders for each combination of ladder operators. They should be considered together. Then things should work out right.